# Swift: How to access one object (ie. a button) within a @IBAction collection to return a sender to a new function?

Tags: ios, function, transform, func, sender

I am creating a simple calculator and I have put a couple of number buttons in an @IBAction. I access a pressed button's sender.title to update the input label like this:

```
 @IBAction func numberButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let numberButton = sender.title(for: .normal) else {return}

        updateInput(num: numberButton)
    }
```

Now I would like to animate each pressed button with a simple CGAFFineTransform (I know how this is done) and I can put the animation into the @IBAction and obviously this works:

```
 @IBAction func numberButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let numberButton = sender.title(for: .normal) else {return}

        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2) // completion handler to reverse the animation

        updateInput(num: numberButton)
    }
```

But I would like to put the animation into another function so that I can access it from different @IBActions and would not have to re-write the code again and again, but I have no idea how I can transfer the "sender" to the new function. 
So how would I tell the new function (let's call it *animateButton()* ) which sender was pressed so that the *sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)...* would know which button to animate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create a function** that receives an `UIButton` as parameter with your animation code inside:

```
func animateButton(anySender: UIButton) {
    // Your animation code here
    sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2) // completion handler to reverse the animation
}
```

**Call your animation** in any function that requires the animation, passing your sender as parameter:

```
@IBAction func numberButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let numberButton = sender.title(for: .normal) else {return}

        animateButton(anySender: sender)
        updateInput(num: numberButton)
    }
```

**EXTRA:** if you need to call this function from different *controllers*, consider making it an `extension`:

```
extension UIButton {
    func customAnimate() {
        // Your animation code here
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2) // completion handler to reverse the animation
    }
}
```

and call it from any button:

```
@IBAction func numberButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let numberButton = sender.title(for: .normal) else {return}

        sender.customAnimate()
        updateInput(num: numberButton)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not think about extensions. That works well!